# how to Create an App Like UPI?

Tags: android

**how UPI android app get sim operator name and send message using selected sim.**

I am using Subscription Manager for getting carrier name. my code getting carrier name is

```
List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptionInfos = SubscriptionManager.from(context).getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();

for (int i = 0; i < subscriptionInfos.size(); i++) 
{
    carrierNames.add(subscriptionInfos.get(i).getCarrierName().toString());
    subscriptionId.add(subscriptionInfos.get(i).getSubscriptionId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager= (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String carrierName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

For Sending SMS, you can do something like this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
new Intent(this, class), 0);                
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, " <your message>", pendingIntent, null);
```

Comment: But how my Server knows about the number that send message.

Comment: App will itself send SMS and if you want to save User's phone number in your server, then send it from your app to server using HttpClient class